# Are nucleic acids found in cell membranes?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

I've found various results online and I was recently marked in on an important test as wrong when I made the assumption they were not found in the cell membrane. Does anyone know what the correct answer is in this case?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nucleic acids are not structural components of cell membranes (ribosomes and nucleus are the main places where they are found).

However, being open system, cell exchanges chemicals with its surrounding and cellular membrane can transport nucleic acids as well. This is why these acids can potentially be detected in the cell membranes.

If you have the exact question expression it can help with more precise answer.

[image]

Comment: Heterochromatin is anchored to the nuclear envelope by lamins, and they actually found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23374351) that this is important in expression and differentiation during development. Not saying that nucleic acid is a core component, but the interactions between that particular membrane and nucleic acid is important. An interesting tidbit to consider, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

No, plasma membrane does not contain any nucleic acids – DNA and RNA. The main components of plasma membrane are lipids, glycol- lipids, phospho lipid bilayer and cholesterol.

Comment: Also contains proteins: https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/cell-membranes-14052567/